# Beginner element problem with single form element and responsive width

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm doing an assignment in Html and CSS using grid layout and I know my code is sloppy since I'm just starting to learn. I have two issues that are preventing me from passing this assignment and they are:

1. have a form element that is as wide as the window when the window is narrower than 600 px

I thought I had that in the code with the width and also my media screen changes the form size when the window is less than 600 px.
Also, I only have one form element, but for some reason, I keep getting the two above mentioned errors when being graded, can someone assist me?

my html and css:

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 1.3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". ." ". ." ". ." ". ." ". .";
  width: 600px;
}
select {
    width: 200px;
}
.name {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}
.type {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}
.bio {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}
.email {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
}
.submit {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
.reset {
  grid-column: 3 / 2;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  button,
  input,
  textarea,
  select,
  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* card */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 344px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.container {
  padding: 16px 16px;
}

div.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
}

div.secondary {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #232F34;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Assessment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your markup goes here. -->
  <form action="/pets" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add Pet</legend>
      <div class="formgrid">
        <div class="name">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
        </div>
        <div class="type">
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <select id="type" name="pet_type">
            <option value="cat">Cat</option>
            <option value="dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            <option value="zebra">Zebra</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
          <label for="bio">Biography</label>
          <textarea id="bio" name="pet_bio"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <label for="owner-email">Owner's Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="owner-email" name="pet_owner_email">
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
          <button type="submit" id="new-pet-submit-button">Create new pet</button>
          <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <!----card---->
  <div class="card">
    <img src="images/desert.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="height:194px" width="344px">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Title goes here</div>
      <div class="secondary">
        <img src="images/person-avatar.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar" style="width:40px">
        Secondary text
        <p>
          Greyhound divisively hello coldly wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.
        </p><br>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: be nice to new contributors? I just edit the question

Comment: the typo in the code was corrected in my editor but still receiving same error when submitting assessment

Comment: I think you need to provide additional detail form your assignment feedback. My suspicion is the second criterion.

Comment: you are correct, i think its an issue with the media screen statement, just edited the post after doing some work, the form element issue is eliminated and the width changed to narrower now, but from my beginners understanding the media screen query i have sets it to the size of the screen. btw sorry if im messing up the post formats, its my first time on this site, still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your width:600px; in the form section to max-width: 600px;

```
    form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 1.3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: ". ." ". ." ". ." ". ." ". .";
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

This will make it responsive while under 600px